# Strategies for using mathematica compiled code on a website?

Tags: compile, deployment

I have developed a chaos detection algorithm which is already used as a compiled (target C) function within Mathematica. The development has been done under Win 10 64-bit with MMA 11.0.1 and the Visual Studio 14 C compiler.

I would like to be able to use this function on a website without needing to incur the costs of licensing any other Wolfram products (about which I know nothing, but maybe wolfram cloud, webmathematica would otherwise be suggested), i.e. to compile the function so that it could be called by some appropriate web technology.

The objective is to allow users to upload sample date from which one or more chaos metrics would then be calculated and displayed, but only the metric calculations need be done with Mathematica derived code.

A colleague would deal with the website implementation, which may of course be running on Linux, and I would also like to be able to suggest appropriate server-side technologies to facilitate the integration.

**Question**: what strategies (especially for code export from MMA and code calling on the web server) would others recommend for deploying compiled Mathematica functions (that do not invoke MainEvaluate, i.e. are entirely self-contained)?

I have tried to fathom the documentation on CreateEexecutable, CreateLibrary, CreateObjectFile but regrettably do not even appreciate the distinctions between them or their potential application in this case.

Comment: I believe it's possible to compile exported LLVM bytecode to WebAssembly using the new `FunctionCompile` technology in version 12, but unfortunately that's not available in version 11...

Comment: @carllange I'll certainly bear that in mind, but as a "Home" user who has bought twice (but, I would like to acknowledge, also received an upgrade from Wolfram due to system compatibility issues) that's another cost I'd like to avoid if at all possible